# Shelf life and Validation of Coconut Milk?

Tags: ingredient-selection, coconut, fresh

I use coconut milk for a pasta dishes, then put the carton back in the fridge.  I may use some of it for a coffee additive, the use plenty more for another pasta dish or recipe.   Alas, I do not cook at home all that often, and sometimes the stored coconut milk tastes bad, so I toss it and go to the store for a fresh carton.

What is the shelf life, in a fridge, of coconut milk?   Is it actually bad if it tastes bad, or could it still be used at least for some purposes?  How to tell if it's about to go bad even if I can't smell anything out of line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refrigerated coconut-based milk substitutes like Silk Pure Coconut or So Delicious Coconut Milk have a stated lifespan of 7-10 days after opening.  I've had cartons last longer than that without any change in taste or smell, but if it started tasting bad or smelling funky I would toss it.  Unfortunately, this type of coconut milk product does not reconstitute well after freezing.

Answer (score 1):

According to Still Tasty, the shelf life of coconut milk is about 4-6 days (it can also be frozen for longer periods; if you use it small quantities, freezing it in an ice cube tray for small portions may be helpful).

There is probably no simple test easily done at home to tell if it is *about* to go bad... your nose is always your best instrument for deciding if it *has* gone off.